# MySQL Join Columns from a table and place into rows in another table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to join columns from Table 1 to rows in Table 2? I understand that MySQL does not have a pivot function. 
To simplify, I have TABLE_1 with 3 columns

```
Id  posted_date     column_1    column_2    column_3
4   2020-05-06      23            54        89
3   2020-05-05      21            49        75
2   2020-05-04      18            47        70
1   2020-05-03      16            40        65
```

From the above table_1 I wish to update the most recent entry (id=4), then each time a new entry goes into table_1 it will automatically update table_2, so when id=5 is input it will overwrite the data in table_2
TABLE_2

```
column     value
column_1    23
column_2    54
column_3    89
```

I have been looking and learning joins, but I can not seem to find a join that will do this.

```
SELECT table_1.column_1, table_1.column_2, table_1.column_3
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
ON table_2.column = ??
```

Comment: There are only ever columns_1 - column_3  in table 1 and 3 rows in table 2?

Comment: You should use an application for formatting data, leave SQL just to fetch it quickly. `SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3 FROM TABLE_1 ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT` gives the information you need.

Comment: Hi danblack, yes that will give me the information I need, but I need to place them into a different table in a column with a row for each along with the value.  Hence why I am trying to do a join between the two tables,

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, Yes the last entry into table-1 for the three columns, I am trying to do a join, so it will take the last entry and place into Table_2 in rows (a row for each column and in table_2 on each row I have the column name and the value, so there would be three rows,  each row has two columns).

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, but I can't see how that helps, I read the page and takes me to fiddle for sql, however doesn't give me answer

Answer (score 0):

After three days looking for a solution I gave up and created a trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `hello` AFTER INSERT ON `table_1`
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table_2;
    INSERT INTO table_2( `column`,`value`)VALUES( 'column_1',NEW.column_1);
    INSERT INTO table_2( `column`,`value`)VALUES( 'column_2',NEW.column_2);
    INSERT INTO table_2( `column`,`value`)VALUES( 'column_3',NEW.column_3);
END;
```